How to include gradle dependencies in osgi bundle using bnd plugin
I want include dependecies in my bundle entry named libs using gradle and the bnd plugin, here is my build.gradle.kts.
import aQute.bnd.gradle.Bundle
import org.osgi.framework.Constants

plugins {
    id("biz.aQute.bnd.builder") version "7.0.0" apply false
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "biz.aQute.bnd.builder")

    tasks.withType<Jar> {
        manifest {
            attributes(
                Constants.IMPORT_PACKAGE to "!kotlin,!kotlin.*,!android.os,*",
                Constants.REQUIRE_BUNDLE to "org.jetbrains.kotlin.osgi-bundle"
            )
        }


        doFirst {
            bundle {
                bnd(mapOf(
                    "-includeresource" to "libs=${configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().map { if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) }.joinToString(",")}"
                ))
            }
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        compileOnly("org.osgi:org.osgi.service.component.annotations:1.5.1")
        compileOnly("org.osgi:osgi.core:8.0.0")
        compileOnly(kotlin("osgi-bundle"))
    }
}

But I got error messages from gradle: Input file does not exist.
I want to automatically detect the runtimeClasspath dependencies and include them in my bundle.
I tried run gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies  but it doesn't help.
